# the server log(localhost:5005) :Engineio.server -http;//localhost:8080 is not an accepted origin"

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

"rasa-Webchat with react on localhost:8080 need connect to the server(rasa) on lcoalhost:5005 based on Ununtu 18.0.4,the server log is: Engineio.server -http;//localhost:8080 is not an accepted origin", but It will work fine in windows environment.

I

Comment: It is very clear what was he asking about. You have running static webserver:8080, that is also proxifying /socket.io to server:5005. When client tries to connect to socket.io server through that proxy - server:5005 will give you exactly that error.. Encountered same stuff. Either proxy needs some very specific configuration, either this is new stupidly coded "feaTchure" that have just broken internets from normal working.. This message popped up during past 15-20 days [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/4204) and [there](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/329) )